# C# Wpf Combobox set selectedvalue, not change selecteditem in UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

i have a combobox inside a usercontrol

```
 <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="CustomerCollection.Description1" SelectedValuePath="CustomerCollection.CustomerID" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Customers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 </ComboBox>
```

My view model have a class model Order, that have a property CustomerID, and inside the view model, i have an observableCollection of customers

```
    private OrderModel _Order;
    public OrderModel Order
    {
        get
        {
            return _Order;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _Order, value);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> _Customers;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> Customers
    {
        get { return _Customers; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Customers, value); }
    }
```

Everything works, but when i set the Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID, so the SelectedValue of my combobox, in the ui not update the selecteditem

```
 private void ReloadCustomers(object CustomerID)
    {
        DialogVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        BackgroundWorker bgwLoad = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwLoad.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>(_customerRepository.Get());
        };
        bgwLoad.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID;

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UIX_MessageEventAggregator.PassParameter>().Unsubscribe(ReloadCustomers);
        };
        bgwLoad.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

i try to implement the override of equals inside Customer, but the stil not working, the only way to get work, seems to create a property of customer inside the viewmodel and binding to selecteditem, but i don't like

```
       public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var customer = obj as CustomerModel;

        if (customer != null)
            return customer.CustomerCollection.CustomerID == CustomerCollection.CustomerID;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CustomerCollection.CustomerID.GetHashCode();
    }
```

i know i missing something, but i can't understand what?
Someone have idea?

```
  public class OrderCollection : _CompanyModel
{
    public OrderCollection(string Vat) : base(Vat)
    {

    }

    #region Core
    private string _OrderID;
    public string OrderID
    {
        get { return _OrderID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _OrderID, value); }
    }

    private long _CustomerID;
    public long CustomerID
    {
        get { return _CustomerID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _CustomerID, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Ok the problem is the BackgroundWorker
This work:

```
private void ReloadCustomers(object CustomerID)
{
   DialogVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

   Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>(_customerRepository.Get());
   Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID;
}
```

This not:

```
private void ReloadCustomers(object CustomerID)
{
            DialogVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            BackgroundWorker bgwLoad = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgwLoad.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>(_customerRepository.Get());
            };
            bgwLoad.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {

                    Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID;
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UIX_MessageEventAggregator.PassParameter>().Unsubscribe(ReloadCustomers);
            };
            bgwLoad.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Show the code for the OrderCollection class, especially the CustomerID property.

Comment: _CompanyModel is BindableBase class (Prism) that implement notifypropertychange

Comment: So the CustomerID property is of type long, but the items source is a collection of CustomerModels, not longs. That means when you select an item the combo box, the selected item is a CustomerModel, which can’t be set via the binding to a property of type long.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that when i set the ordercollection.customerid inside the bgwLoad.RunWorkerCompleted, the selecteditem of combobox doesn't update, if i set in a simple command it works

Comment: Ok sorry, on a small screen and I didn’t scroll over enough to see your SelectedValuePath. You really should format your xaml one attribute per line.

Comment: The problem is the background worker, i edit the post, with the method without and work

Answer (score 0):

as you did not post the content of the OrderCollection class this is just an assumption. But my best guess is that you don't raise a `PropertyChangedEvent` when you set the `CustomerID` property in the `OrderCollection`.
Therefore the View never gets notified about the change in selection.

So changing the model implementation to raise a property changed even for your CustomID *should* fix the issue.
However you might not want to *pollute* your Model with such events. Another option could be to wrap your models (Customer, Order) in dedicated ViewModels and raise the events in there where needed.

Comment: i have the propertychanged inside the view model, and it fire when i set the order.customerid.                                                https://ibb.co/hxcN97

Comment: So you do fire it after you do `Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID;`?
How do you fire it? As it seems not to be included in your sample code.

Comment: Exactly, i'm using prism:
        private long _CustomerID;
        public long CustomerID
        {
            get { return _CustomerID; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _CustomerID, value); }
        }

Comment: Could it then be that the issue is that you run that code in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler. Try invokoking the code that should update the UI via dispatcher:
`Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID)`

Comment: No, i try, with application.current.Dispatcher... but still not work, i try to add a command where i set just the order.customerid, and it work.. so the problem is really about the runworkercompleted.. but the itemssource, is updated when i try to set. When i execute this, it update correctly:    private void SelectCustomerExecute(object Dialog)
        {
            Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = 10;
        }

Comment: ok, then I'm not sure what else could be the issue.
One thing that you could try is changing  
`Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>(_customerRepository.Get());` to  
`Customers.Clear();  Customers.AddRange(_customerRepository.Get())`. 

As you use an `ObservableCollection` you don't have to change the complete list but just it's content. Then you can get rid of the Setter of the *Customers Property* as well, just initialize it to an empty list in the constructor.
Maybe this causes some issues...

Comment: Nothing.. i'm going crazy :)

Comment: If you're able to share your project (or extract the necessary parts into a demo project) that would help so it could be checked in more detail. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: i have to extract

Comment: The problem is the background worker, i edit the post, with the method without and work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was inside BackgroundWorker, i've repleced with

```
      await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>(_customerRepository.Get());
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Order.OrderCollection.CustomerID = (long)CustomerID;
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UIX_GlobalEvent.PassParameter>().Unsubscribe(ReloadCustomers);
        });
```